# Google Sheet SUMIF with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a SUMIF using IMPORTRANGE but apparently that cannot be done in Google Sheets. How else can I create the following and have it work in Google Sheets?

```
=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("URL","SHEET1!$A:$A"),$E:$E,SHEET1!$H:$H)
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to share the sheet with the public. Sorry but thanks for offering.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this myself using the following formual:

```
=IF(A2 = "","",IFERROR(SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "SHEET1!$A:$H"),"select Col8 where Col1 = '"&$E2&"'",0)*-1)))
```